# Chat notification bar issues

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, chat, notification-bar

I'm confident we all *love* StackExchange [everbeautiful](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/) notification bars.
They are [gorgeous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605291/header-message-just-like-at-stack-overflow), look and behave similar, have fixed height and disappear with a fadeaway and a slide-up.

[image: StackOverflow notification bar]
[image: Programmers.SE notification bar]

*Lovely, aren't they?*

However, a similar notification bar on [Chat.SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com)/[Chat.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com), to me, doesn't quite hit the mark; in fact, it **annoys** me.

[image]

My hatred is fueled  and fed by a number of reasons:

- It seems to **pop up at random times** (once a day?) and mentions I need to have some rep when **the site itself has recognized me straight away** (see the handwritten message).
- I reach out to the right to get rid of it and then realize there is no close button in the right corner!

  [image]

  Instead, *unlike on any other StackExchange site*, there is a label in a small font below the message. (Visible on the first screenshot if you *haven't noticed it right away*).
- Err, well. Let's click it. What happens? Instead of the gorgeous “fade away, then slide up” animation, the pseudobar gradually decreases its height, **chewing up the text on the way**.

  [image: Goat chewing grass]
  *Goat chewing grass by [Stuart Chalmers](http://www.flickr.com/photos/gertcha/)*

Well, obviously I'm not happy with that.

While I'm perfectly fine with the styling (font and colors), I'd like my “close” button in its *rightful* place, the bar popping up when **it's got something to tell me** and the text not being chewed up as, however useless it may be, I do feel sorry for it.

Comment: Good post, that drives me crazy also.